# Windows 2012 Cluster on P6300 SCSI-3 Persistent Reservation issues

Tags: cluster, windows-server-2012, hp-storageworks

**Scenario:**

1 HP 6300 with latest XCS version

1 Command View 10.1 + with hosts defined as Windows 2008

2 BL460c Gen8 Servers with SPP 2012.10 and Windows Server 2012 Datacenter Edition with all the updates + MPIO feature enabled

DSM v4.03.00

**Cluster Analyser Tool triggers this error:**

Test Disk 0 does not support SCSI-3 Persistent Reservations commands needed to support clustered Storage Pools. Some storage devices require specific firmware versions or settings to function properly with failover clusters. Please contact your storage administrator or storage vendor to check the configuration of the storage to allow it to function properly with failover clusters.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are the luns configured for shared useage?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tony. But, I don't understand your question. In Command View EVA there isn't any option to setup a shared LUN that I am aware of. The LUNs were first created at the array level and then presented to both servers. I have installed many similar environments but with Windows 2008 without any issues.
I think that in Windows 2012, there's something different regarding SCSI-3 Persistent Reservations... Or the HP DSM for Windows 2012 is not quite stable yet... The DSM release notes say that Windows 2012 support was added but not any particular configuration for clustering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that's a new feature on Windows 2012 named Storage Spaces.

Cluster Analyser Tool validates if this feature is available or not but it does not compromise cluster functionality.

Microsoft Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831739.aspx states that in order for this feature to work you'll need:

"Serial ATA (SATA) or Serial Attached SCSI (SAS) connected disks, optionally in a just-a-bunch-of-disks (JBOD) enclosure. **RAID adapters, if used, must have all RAID functionality disabled and must not obscure any attached devices, including enclosure services provided by an attached JBOD.**"

In this scenario, since the harddrives are behind FC RAID Controllers with RAID configured it does not meet Storage Spaces requirements, so it triggers the warning.

No issues were detected after creating the cluster.